# Installshield 2008 trying to change INSTALLDIR

Tags: windows, installation, installshield

I am to refactor a legacy application that is using installshield 2008 to create an installer.  I have no option to convert the project to a newer version and I am pretty much newbie to installshield. I am trying to change the INSTALLDIR to be `C:\ProgramFiles\MyProduct` instead of `C:\ProgramFiles(x86)\MyProduct`.

Here is what I tried: from General Information -> Product Properties I changed INSTALLDIR value from `[ProgramFilesFolder]\MyProduct` to `[ProgramFiles64Folder]\MyProduct` but when I build the installer and run it nothing changes - still C:\Program Files(x86) is used.

Then I did another experiment - I tried to set a hard coded path for INSTALLDIR for instance `INSTALLDIR=C:\temp\MyProduct` Now when I build and run the installer it crashes with the error: `The installation package could not be opened. Contact the application vendor to verify that this is a valid Windows Installer Package`. I do not understand why this happens. Any ideas on what am I doing wrong? Maybe the INSTALLDIR should be set from somewhere else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are installing 64-bit executables (which I infer from your INSTALLDIR setting) you must make your installation a 64-bit installation.
 In General Information -> Summary Information Stream, set one of the Template Summary values to be "x64", replacing "Intel".
  You can allow the user to change the default INSTALLDIR in the Destination Folder dialog.
  You can create a Type 35 (set a directory) custom action, which must follow the CostFinalize action in both sequences, to set INSTALLDIR from a property or a string.
  Good luck, Rob